# Group By and list not matched

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have table as under:

```
Col1        Col2                Col3    Col4                    Col5
1           50.9499411799115    Point   imp                     A
1           109.69487431133     Point   exp                     1
1           107.69487431133     Point   exp                     2
1           1019.69487431133    Point   exp                     B
2           51.5403193833315    Point   imp                     0
2           50.5403193833315    Point   exp                     3
```

I want to group by Col1 and select all the ones where there are no 'A' or 'B' in Col5

I used the below query for generating the ouput in MSSQL but didnt get correct result, can someone point out my mistake

```
SELECT Col1
FROM table1
WHERE
    Col5 NOT LIKE('%A%')
or  Col5 NOT LIKE('%B%')
GROUP BY Col1;
```

Therefore my output should be

```
Col1 
2
```

Comment: @Duffer: But if your Col5 having "A" & "B" as value then why are you trying for LIKE operator. Simply use Col5 NOT IN ('A','B')

Comment: Yes, but I want to eleminate any Col1 which atleast 1 'A' or 'B' in Col5 therefore I was grouping by Col1

Comment: There are a number of ways you can do this... For example, you can use `NOT EXISTS` or `EXCEPT` or a left self join where null... As a quick example: `SELECT Col1 FROM table1 AS T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS T2 WHERE T2.Col1 = T1.Col1 AND T2.Col5 LIKE '%[AB]%') GROUP BY Col1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to eliminate one row based on data in another, so the only way to do that is to check the other day e.g.

```
select Col1
from table1 D1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 D2 where D2.Col1 = D1.Col1 and (Col5 like ('%A%') or Col5 like ('%B%')))
group by Col1
```